# Splitting collection into equal batches in Parallel using c#

Tags: c#, performance

I am trying to split collection into equal number of batches.below is the code.

```
   public static List<List<T>> SplitIntoBatches<T>(List<T> collection, int size)
    {
        var chunks = new List<List<T>>();
        var count = 0;
        var temp = new List<T>();

        foreach (var element in collection)
        {
            if (count++ == size)
            {
                chunks.Add(temp);
                temp = new List<T>();
                count = 1;
            }
            temp.Add(element);
        }

        chunks.Add(temp);

        return chunks;
    }
```

can we do it using `Parallel.ForEach()` for better performance as we have around 1 Million items in the list?

Thanks!

Comment: Aside from the performance, MoreLinq's `Batch()` method already does this, with delayed execution. A really good answer would depend on what you want to do with the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is the concern, my thoughts (in increasing order of impact):

- right-sizing the lists when you create them would save a *lot* of work, i.e. figure out the output batch sizes *before* you start copying, i.e. `temp = new List<T>(thisChunkSize)`
- working with arrays would be more effective than working with lists - `new T[thisChunkSize]`
- especially if you use `BlockCopy` (or `CopyTo`, which uses that internally) rather than copying individual elements one by one
- once you've calculated the offsets for each of the chunks, the individual block-copies could probably be executed in parallel, but I wouldn't assume it will be faster - memory bandwidth will be the limiting factor at that point
- but the *ultimate* fix is: **don't copy the data at all**, but instead just create *ranges* over the existing data; for example, if using arrays, `ArraySegment<T>` would help; if you're open to using newer .NET features, this is a perfect fit for `Memory<T>`/`Span<T>` - creating memory/span ranges over an existing array is essentially free and instant - i.e. take a `T[]` and return `List<Memory<T>>` or similar.

Even if you can't switch to `ArraySegment<T>` / `Memory<T>` etc, returning something *like* that could still be used - i.e. `List<ListSegment<T>>` where `ListSegment<T>` is something like:

```
readonly struct ListSegment<T> { // like ArraySegment<T>, but for List<T>
    public List<T> List {get;}
    public int Offset {get;}
    public int Count {get;}
}
```

and have your code work with `ListSegment<T>` by processing the `Offset` and `Count` appropriately.